# (Cordova/Phonegap) Android splash screen not being shown using Android Studio builds

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I have the following product flavors  in module's *build.gradle*

```
productFlavors {
    pro {
        applicationId "com.icounttimer.android"
    }
    free {
        applicationId "com.icounttimer.android.free"
    }
}
```

The package structure of my app module is:

```
src/main/java/com/icounttimer/android/MainActivity.java
```

Building *pro-debug.apk* shows the splashscreen correctly. However, *free-debug.apk* does not show the splashscreen.

Changing the applicationId of 'free' flavor to *'com.icounttimer.android'* resolves the issue. But when using a different applicationId, the splash screen won't be shown.

Environment:

- CordovaLib: v3.6.3
- Android Studio 1.0 RC4

What is the reason for this behaviour and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason which I found is as follows:

Changing *applicationId* via build.gradle, changes the app's package name.

**Note that it is different from the package structure of the app** which remains unaltered during different build variants.

The app package structure, in this case, is unaltered: src/main/java/com/icounttimer/android/MainActivity.java

Diving through the code, I found out that the showSplashScreen() methods in *CordovaActivity.java* (part of CordovaLib) get the resources as follows:

```
this.splashscreen = getResources().getIdentifier(splash, "drawable", getClass().getPackage().getName());
```

The third arguments for getIdentifier(...) method is the package name of app.

```
getClass().getPackage().getName()
```

gets the pkgName based on package structure which always returns *'com.icounttimer.android'* no matter which build variant it is.

To fix this, replace both of its occurences in CordovaActivity.java with:

```
this.getPackageName() //returns the name of the application pkg which is the applicationId
```